# LinkedIn API V2 Rich Media (image) posts not showing up

Tags: c#, api, linkedin-api

I'm using the Rich Media API (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares) to post an image to LinkedIn, but not all my posts are showing up.

I have used multiple accounts (both personal and organization) and I always get a 201 Created HTTP status code when posting, but I can't find most of the messages. Usually only the first message I'm posting with an account shows up, any messages after that still get the 201 Created but don't show up on LinkedIn.

If I try to use the ID that is in the response to my API request to find the message on LinkedIn, I get an error "Oops! It’s not you. It’s us. Give it another try, please."

What am I doing wrong?

***Edit***: I have found the issue. Turns out you have to specify an empty linkedInDistributionTarget in your JSON. When you omit it, the message will be a dark post, see: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api#distribution-targets

Comment: Erik, did you have to request special permissions from LinkedIn to access the V2 API (e.g. Rich Media endpoints)? I'm trying to use it, but I keep on getting errors saying things like "Not enough permissions to access /shares FINDER owners". The access token I'm testing with has the scopes: 'r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'w_share', 'rw_company_admin'

Comment: So where to ask for the V2 API access?

Comment: I'm having same issue

Comment: me too facing the same issue. Do share the solution.

Comment: Same issue, any solution??